# Convert a Python list of dictionaries with list value to a flat list of dictionary with single value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value, flatten

### The problem statement

Given a list of dictionaries:

```
p = [
     {'x': 1, 
      'a': [12, 14, 16], 
      'b': [13, 15], 
      'y': 8},
     {'x': 2, 
      'a': [22, 24], 
      'b': [23, 25, 27], 
      'y': 9}
    ]
```

with some keys (`'a'` and `'b'`) in the form of lists, while others (`'x'` and `'y'`) as single values--
I'd like to create a rather flat dictionary, where the **list** key-values are segregated into separate keys `'a_1'`, `'a_2'`, ..., `'b_1'`, `'b_2'`, ..., etc. while keeping the **single** key-values as it is.

```
t = [
     {'x': 1, 
      'a_1': 12, 
      'a_2': 14, 
      'a_3': 16, 
      'b_1': 13, 
      'b_2': 15, 
      'y': 8},
     {'x': 2, 
      'a_1': 22, 
      'a_2': 24, 
      'b_1': 23, 
      'b_2': 25, 
      'b_3': 27, 
      'y': 9}
    ]
```

### A partial solution

I was able to convert just one key `'a'` having a list value to a dictionary with single values with the code:

```
q = [{'a_'+str(i+1): obj['a'][i]
        for i in range(len(obj['a']))} 
            for obj in p]
print (q)
```

which gives an output looking like:

```
[
 {'a_1': 12, 
  'a_2': 14, 
  'a_3': 16},
 {'a_1': 22, 
  'a_2': 24}
]
```

but no idea how to do that for multiple keys... particularly to do this for those keys whose value is of type `list`, and simply keep the key-value otherwise... and finally merging all the key-values into one dictionary within the outer loop `for obj in p`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a nested iteration, `isinstance` to check the type and `enumerate` to get index of item

**Ex:**

```
result = []
for i in p:
    temp = {}
    for k, v in i.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            for idx,j in enumerate(v, 1):
                temp[f"{k}_{idx}"] = j
        else:
            temp[k] = v
    result.append(temp)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'a_1': 12, 'a_2': 14, 'a_3': 16, 'b_1': 13, 'b_2': 15, 'x': 1, 'y': 8},
 {'a_1': 22, 'a_2': 24, 'b_1': 23, 'b_2': 25, 'b_3': 27, 'x': 2, 'y': 9}]
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh. I liked your answer in comparison to @adir abargil's as I need it just once... and I'd hate to define a separate function for that.  Otherwise both are equally acceptable.

Comment: Was wondering if this could be done with the list-comprehension style-- which makes it compact and (debatably, though) more readable !?

Comment: I don't think so.. it will also definitely be a bad coding style to have multiple nested loof and if conditions in a list comprehension

Comment: In one sense, I agree. However, a [mid-way solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66952645/8854526) might not look not so bad ?!

Comment: totally agree with Rakesh, though I provided an example of one...

Answer (score 2):

you can do as follows:

```
def parse_dict(d):
    new_dict = {}
    for key,val in d.items():
        if isinstance(val,list):
            new_dict.update({f'{key}_{i+1}':v for i,v in enumerate(val)})
        else:
            new_dict[key] = val
    return new_dict

result = [parse_dict(d) for d in p]
```

the output of result:

```
[{'x': 1, 'a_1': 12, 'a_2': 14, 'a_3': 16, 'b_1': 13, 'b_2': 15, 'y': 8},
 {'x': 2, 'a_1': 22, 'a_2': 24, 'b_1': 23, 'b_2': 25, 'b_3': 27, 'y': 9}]
```

the main idea was to separate responsibilities by creating a new function and then think elementwise...

hope this helps more then just solves the issue.

#### update:

if you insist in not making a function and finding  a one  (long and unreadable) one liner:

```
[ {**{key:val for key,val in d.items() if not isinstance(val,list)},**{f'{key}_{i}' if isinstance(val,list)else key : v if isinstance(val,list)else val for key,val in d.items() if isinstance(val,list) for i,v in enumerate(val)}} for d in p]
```

output:

```
[{'x': 1, 'y': 8, 'a_0': 12, 'a_1': 14, 'a_2': 16, 'b_0': 13, 'b_1': 15},
 {'x': 2, 'y': 9, 'a_0': 22, 'a_1': 24, 'b_0': 23, 'b_1': 25, 'b_2': 27}]
```

(notice that the order has changed)

Comment: Hmm... looks like the longer solution (rather than your later "edit") is more comprehendible !  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
p = [{'x': 1, 'a': [12, 14, 16], 'b': [13, 15], 'y': 8}, {'x': 2, 'a': [22, 24], 'b': [23, 25, 27], 'y': 9}]
r = [{a if not isinstance(b, list) else f'{a}_{l}':b if not isinstance(b, list) else j 
     for a, b in i.items() for l, j in enumerate((b if isinstance(b, list) else [b]), 1)} 
         for i in p]
```

Output:

```
[{'x': 1, 'a_1': 12, 'a_2': 14, 'a_3': 16, 'b_1': 13, 'b_2': 15, 'y': 8}, {'x': 2, 'a_1': 22, 'a_2': 24, 'b_1': 23, 'b_2': 25, 'b_3': 27, 'y': 9}]
```

Comment: Huh !  3 `for`s are understandable... but 3 `if`s and 3 `else`s make the one-liner really hard to digest.  As an after-thought, my wish for list-comprehension sounds like a [_monkey's paw_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monkey%27s_Paw) to me the next day of the wish !!  But thank you, nonetheless for the wonderful solution !!!

Answer (score 0):

What you demanding is little tricky but I gonna try my best.
Lets continue it,

So the way i faund is using functions(definitions)

```
def get_new(l):
    N = l.copy()
    for a in range(len(N)):
        for b in N[a].keys():
            if b in ['a','b']:
                i = 1
                while N[a][b]: # while N[a][b] is not empty.
                    key = str(b) + '_' + str(i)
                    i += 1
                    N[a][key] = N[a][b].pop(0)
                del N[a][b]
    
    return N
```

*above function take your initial list and return the list you demanded*

Function loops in dictionary and inside it  key and for every 'a' and 'b' key it will change keys every list value
*keys like* str(a)+'_'+i

*i is perfectly index +1*

*values as* N[a][b][i] # because it pop out index 0 every time.

*delete* N[a][b] when its particular key-value is prepared.

Answer (score 0):

I *was* able to come up with (again a partial) list-comprehension style solution:

```
t = []
for obj in p:
    t.append(dict([]))
    [t[-1].update({key+'_'+str(i+1): val[i]
        for i in range(len(obj[key]))}) 
           if isinstance(obj[key], list) else
     t[-1].update({key: val})
        for key, val in zip(obj.keys(), obj.values()) 
    ]
```

One explicit loop for the items (`obj`) in `p`, where a new dictionary is created inside the loop, and term(s) added to it depending on whether the item-value is a list or not... thanks to my preceding answerers for pointing out the `isinstance(obj, type)` function.

So, printing `t` gives:

```
[{'x': 1, 'a_1': 12, 'a_2': 14, 'a_3': 16, 'b_1': 13, 'b_2': 15, 'y': 8},
 {'x': 2, 'a_1': 22, 'a_2': 24, 'b_1': 23, 'b_2': 25, 'b_3': 27, 'y': 9}]
```

A *not-to-be-so-proud-of* plus point of this solution is: it doesn't use the `f'{key}_{i+1}'` feature (which, though both the elegant solvers have used, seems rather a bit obscure to me-- pardon my ignorance) !